# Install and connect to database with psql

Tags: database, postgresql, centos

I want to set up the psql terminal tool in Centos 6.6

I have been given access to as database and i just want to use the terminal for writing queries to the database for information. I have no prior experience with psql before but I want to move on from the pgadmin3 gui.

I started off by installing psql:

```
yum install postgresql
```

but when I try to access it, ie. typing  `[root@localhost]# psql` I get the following error:

```
psql: FATAL:  database "root" does not exist
```

I've tried using:

```
psql --host=<DB instance endpoint> --port=<port> --username=<master user name> --password --dbname=<database name>
```

but that fails to work too, maybe this is really basic but im completely lost for setting this up

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use:

```
psql -U my_pgadmin_username postgres
```

or

```
psql -U my_pgadmin_username -h localhost postgres
```

Alternately, more typical usage:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

Comment: So i can access it when i type:  psql -d 'DBNAME' -h 'HOSTNAME' -p PORT -U 'USERNAME', but i cant query it  at all, it just accepts my commands and returns nothing